# UITraitCollection remains same for iPhone / iPad

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, size-classes, uitraitcollection

In iOS 8.3, I present a view controller with the following code:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Upon presentation in my iPad simulator, I check the UITraitCollection property of my view (`po self.traitCollection`) in the `viewDidLoad()` method and here is what I get:

```
<_UITraitNameHorizontalSizeClass = Regular, 
_UITraitNameVerticalSizeClass = Regular>
```

**I switch the simulator from iPad to iPhone (5s or 6) and I still get the Regular horizontal size class trait in my view. iPhones should have an Compact horizontal size class trait.**

Since the horizontal size class is wrong, the wrong size class design is loaded from the storyboard. Any ideas why the framework is providing a wrong size class?